# get list of DLs few users are member of

Tags: powershell, active-directory, distribution-list

I am beginner in powershell and trying to create a script.
I have list of users, for them I need to know in which DLs they are added.

The problem I am facing is, it shows the list of DLs only, is there any way I can get DLs under the usernames? or a better way to accomplish this.

Note: we name all our  DLs in capital letter thats why I have used "\b[A-Z0-9_]+\b" in where-object.

```
$users = import-csv C:\Test\users.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.users = $_.users.Trim(); $_}  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty users

foreach ( $user in $users)

{get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name |

Where-Object { $_.name -cmatch "\b[A-Z0-9_]+\b"} | Export-CSV "C:\test\output_file.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

}
```

Now I get the following outcome:

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
Group2
Group3
Group4
```

My ideal out put would be something along the lines of:

```
User  MemberOf
----  --------
Bob   Group1, Group2, Group3....
Jim   Group2, Group3, Group4....
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: Do you only want to target Distribution Lists or Security Groups too?

Comment: @santiago Only Distribution Lists. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for **Distribution Lists**, you can tell if a group is a *Security Group* or a *Distribution List* by looking at the `GroupCategory` property of an `ADGroup` object.

Instead of looking at the user's `memberOf` attribute and finding out which ones are `Distribution` you can search for `ADGroups` that are **`GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution'`** where ***each*** user is a `member`:

```
$users = (Import-CSV C:\Test\users.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.users.Trim()
}).users

$result = foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $userDN = (Get-ADUser $user).DistinguishedName
    $groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "member -eq '$userDN' -and groupCategory -eq 'Distribution'"
    
    [pscustomobject]@{
        User = $user
        MemberOf = $groups.Name -join ', '
    }
}

$result | Export-CSV "C:\test\output_file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

If you want to use the code you already have, with this minor update you should be getting the result you are looking for:

```
$users = (Import-CSV C:\Test\users.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.users.Trim()
}).users

$result = foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $membership = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user |
    Where-Object {
        $_.name -cmatch "\b[A-Z0-9_]+\b"
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        User = $user
        MemberOf = $membership.Name -join ', '
    }
}

$result | Export-CSV "C:\test\output_file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```